# Geonodes delete points too close to main point

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I am making a points collision solver in simulation nodes. Long story short I have a problem, when a sphere is inside a bigger sphere and has a close neighbor with same problem, they do not detect bigger circle as too close one. So I want to delete them if they are inside for too long. The basic idea is to detect nearest point with index of nearest point and if it is too close to the point, mark it as an inside point an create timer. If it stays inside for few steps, delete it. The problem is I can't find a way to store attribute by index.

The main point has 3 points too close to them, so I find the closest one and want to delete it.
[image]

[image: Node setup that should detect points that are to close and than count how long they are too close, and if they are close for too long-delete them]

But this setup does not work.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: It seems your problem stems from using "nearest neighbor", but instead you need to iterate over all neighbors within some threshold. Hard to advise something without knowing what exactly you want to achieve (where do the inner spheres comes from?), but you could take a look at my answer here on how to check multiple nearest elements: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293797/60486

Comment: Feels like i can solve my problem with your answer, TY