# Count "neighbouring points" in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

"Sample Nearest" or "Index of Nearest" gives us a single point of data, but I'm scratching my head on how to count *multiple* neighbouring points in a given range.   Essentially I want to add a dynamic "pointDensity" named attribute to each point given its proximity to others using a map range.  Basically a heat map of proximity.

I'm absolutely stumped, yet I suspect I'm missing something simple.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could use this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293797/60486 then count edges…

Comment: Do you mean connected points?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this solution to connect the points with edges and then count the edges:

[Selectively join points using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293797/60486)

In Blender 4.0 onward you can use a repeat zone like so:

[image]

[image]

Instead of using a threshold you could just sum up the distances…