# Connecting object vertices between objects in geometry nodes with lines

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using geometry nodes, can I create curves between all vertices of two objects?

I'm hoping to produce the following result, where you can see all three vertices of each object are connected resulting in a total of 9 curves.

[image: Two objects with all 3 vertices connected by curves]

So far, I've only been able to connect to the *nearest* index of the other object, shown here: [image: Nearest vertex curves]

produced by this node tree:

[image: Nodes for nearest vertex curves]

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look here ["How do i connect points A to B following the sphere curve, and then add some height ad midpoint of the curve? (Flightpaths)"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/310585/177431): one point (hub airport) is connected to a collection of points (other airports). If you are using Blender 4, you can then use a loop over one object points to connect to the other object points.

Answer (score 5):

You can, if you like,  do this without a repeat-zone..

- Instance a cluster of (`target_vertex_count`) duplicate edges on each vertex of the source mesh, stashing the `duplicate_index` of the edges in each cluster
- Move the endpoints of each realized edge to the stashed `duplicate_index` vertex position of the target mesh:

[image]

thus:

[image]

[image]

Comment: very nice one!! +1

Answer (score 3):

one way of doing this is using two nested repeat zones, so that you can iterate for each index of one mesh over each index of the other mesh like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use indices to place all the wanted segments:

[image]

Get the domain sizes of the two initial meshes. Multiply them to duplicate a segment.

Get the index of the vertices from the duplicated and get half of it (this half indicate one segment).

This modulo the first object size allows to pick a position onto the first mesh.

And divided by this same size allows to pick a position onto the second mesh.

Keep one or the other depending on the parity of the index.

[image]

[image] (File in Blender 4.0, but the node tree will work with 3.6)

PS: of course if you want curves, start with a curve line instead of mesh line and duplicate the splines instead of the segments.

Comment: Answers 1 second apart... I think they're distinct enough..

Comment: @RobinBetts They are and yours is more simple (1 hour apart, do you mean?)

Comment: It's weird how delivery syncs up.. I got notification when I was nearly finished...

Answer (score 1):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

Following is an approach quite similar to [lemon's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/310935/177431), but keeping instances instead of "realized" objects.
It is assumed that all transformations were ["applied"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) to the curve to instance. Furthermore, its Z axis will be aligned between connected vertices. So its size along this axis must be equal to 1. Beside, its origin is put at mid-height along this axis.

[image: GN graph with instances of curve on a point cloud]

**1.** Let $nS$ and $nT$ be [the number of vertices](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/domain_size.html) in *Source* and *Target* geometries, respectively. A [*Points*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/points.html) node is creating a $nS \times nT$ points cloud, used afterwards to instance the curve.
**2.** Such a point index (labelled $i$) is split to recover the index of a *Target* vertex (labelled $iT$) and the index of a *Source* vertex (labelled $iS$). Arbitrarily, $i$ is defined as $i = iT + nT  \times iS$ *(NB: index values start at 0, not 1)*. So:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
i & \equiv & iT \pmod {nT} \\
iS & = & (i - iT)\ /\ nT \end{array}$$
**3.** The position of the *Target* (resp. *Source*) vertex with index $iT$ (resp. $iS$) is recovered through a [*Sample Index*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/sample/sample_index.html) node set in *Point* domain. It is labelled $\vec{T}$ (resp. $\vec{S}$).
**4.** Transformations of the curve to instance are computed from $\vec{S}$ and $\vec{T}$.
**4.1.** The mid-point between *S* and *T* is used to put the curve origin. It is defined by $\frac{1}{2}(\vec{T}+\vec{S})$.
**4.2.** The curve local Z axis is aligned to the vector connecting *S* to *T*. It is defined by $\vec{T}-\vec{S}$.
**4.3.** The distance between *S* and *T* is used to scale the curve along its local Z axis. The scaling factors are defined by $(1,1,\|\vec{T}-\vec{S}\|)$.
**5.** An [*Instance on Points*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/instance_on_points.html) node is creating curve instances, using the position, rotation and scaling factors computed at step 4.

**Resources:** [image]